# MongoDB cannot project string value from _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an aggregate to pull metrics from a collection of "share" actions. These metrics are grouped by day and the platform(twitter, pintrest, etc). Each stage works fine except when it comes to formatting the output in a `$project` stage, I cannot seem to get the `platform` string to project in my output. I see it in the _id still, however I cannot get it to project to the other field.

The aggregation is as follows:

```
{
  $unwind: "$platforms"
},
{
  $project: {
    day: {$dayOfMonth: "$created_at"},
    month: {$month: "$created_at"},
    year: {$year: "$created_at"},
    platforms: 1
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      platorms: "$platforms",
      day: "$day",
      month: "$month",
      year: "$year"
    },
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    day: "$_id.day",
    month: "$_id.month",
    year: "$_id.year",
    platform: "$_id.platforms",
    count: 1
  }
}
```

The output of the following is:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "platorms" : "EMAIL",
            "day" : 28,
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2015
        },
        "count" : 1,
        "day" : 28,
        "month" : 4,
        "year" : 2015
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "platorms" : "EMAIL",
            "day" : 27,
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2015
        },
        "count" : 10,
        "day" : 27,
        "month" : 4,
        "year" : 2015
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "platorms" : "SMS",
            "day" : 27,
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2015
        },
        "count" : 1,
        "day" : 27,
        "month" : 4,
        "year" : 2015
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "platorms" : "FACEBOOK",
            "day" : 27,
            "month" : 4,
            "year" : 2015
        },
        "count" : 1,
        "day" : 27,
        "month" : 4,
        "year" : 2015
    }, ...
```

The integers for day, month, and year project fine, however platforms does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your `$group` stage you have compound `_id` with `platorms: "$platforms"` (missing `f` in field name) and you are projecting the `$_id.platforms` in your last `$project` stage and since such field doesn't exist you will not get any result. You can also exclude the `_id` field using `_id: 0`.

Change your `$group` stage to:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      platforms: "$platforms",
      day: "$day",
      month: "$month",
      year: "$year"
    },
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, you caught it. I was missing the "f" in platforms. Was totally a typo on my part. This seems to be the problem.